# How to access user directory in lazarus?

Tags: lazarus

I'm trying to open file `changelog.txt` and I need to open it no matter what user is opening it. It's however always located in `~/` directory. Access the file. Here's my code:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var myFile : TextFile;
    line   : string;
begin
     AssignFile(myFile, '~/changelog.txt');
     Reset(myFile);
       while not Eof(myFile) do
       begin
            ReadLn(myFile, line);
            Label3.Caption := (Label3.Caption + line + #13#10);
       end;
       CloseFile(myFile);
end;
```

It doesn't work. However, if I replace `~` with the actual  username, it works. However, I cannot know the username of each user that will run my program. Any ideas how can I get the username of user that started the program? Thanks!

Edit1: I have tried this, but it also includes a new line:

```
RunCommand('/bin/bash',['-c','whoami'],user);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is normal.  "~" is a *shell* level concept and thus needs a separate shell invocation to evaluate. Assignfile calls the kernel interfaces directly though and thus doesn't understand this.

Use [getenvironmentvariable](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/sysutils/getenvironmentvariable.html)('HOME') to get the homedir from the environment. Better even, [getuserdir](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/sysutils/getuserdir.html) allows to get the home dir in a crossplatform manner.

Comment: SysUtils.GetUserDir - for *nix it is same as getenvironmentvariable('HOME') but it is also crossplatform.